# Handle a custom component using React Hook Forms and React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-hook-form

I'm trying to set up a custom component to my react-hook-forms and react-table

```
const selectedUserIds =  watch(`user_ids`) || [];

<Controller
  control={control}
  name={fieldName("user_ids")}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
  <UserTable selectedUserIds={selectedUserIds} updatePropertySelection={onChange}/>
)}
/>
```

UserTable:

```
function updatePropertyTableSelection(ids){
  const ids = extractIds(ids);
  updatePropertySelection(ids);
}

const selectedUserIdsForTable = convertIdsToTableFormat(selectedUserIds)
return (
<React.Fragment>
    <BasicTable
        tableHeader={() => null}
        columns={[
          {
            Header: "User Name",
            accessor: "attributes.name",
          }
        ]}
        data={data}
        selectedRows={selectedUserIdsForTable}
        onSelectedRowsChange={updatePropertyTableSelection}
      />
</React.Fragment>
)
```

When I associate the onChange handler to updatePropertySelection I get stuck in an infinite rerender. How should I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and I fix it by following this:

1. First one, my issue comes from the old react-hook-form, now I'm using `^7.14.2` and its resolve issue.
2. Second solution fixed issue by replacing `onChange` to `field.onChange`
   for example (from real project):

   ```
   <Controller
     name={"explanation"}
     control={props.control}
     render={({field}) => {
       return (
         <MyEditor
           placeholder={t("onlineAssessments.question.explanationPlaceholder")}
           onPressEnter={props.onPressEnter}
           onChange={(val, editor) => {
               // notify parent 
               field.onChange(val);

               // calc count
               setExplanationCount(editor?.getBody().innerText.trim().length)
             }
           }
         />
       )
     }
     }
   />
   ```

and I think this change comes from the latest update..

3. May you have something keep re-render trigger, base on your table, you may need to `useCallBack` or `useMemo` to prevent re-render on each visit else if dependency change, for example:

   ```
   const updatePropertyTableSelection = useCallBack((ids) => {
     const ids = extractIds(ids);
     updatePropertySelection(ids);
   }, []);
   ```

   and

   ```
   const selectedUserIdsForTable = useMemp(() => { convertIdsToTableFormat(selectedUserIds)
   }, []);
   ```

Note: Don't forget to update dependency only if it's needed and only to what you needed to re-render

Comment: the useCallBack worked like a charm. Thanks so much, have a great day!

Comment: Amazing to hear that!, Thanks!